# Chrome's subpixel rendering affecting fixed/absolute positioned elements

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, electron

I have a electron based application that provides a CAD like experience for mining engineers.  This software includes a crosshair cursor:

[wide cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gp0k.png)

that is styled as so:

```
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
```

The four crosshair segments are children of the div with the previous style, and each crosshair has an absolute position and width / border as a style:

```
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
```

Depending on where the cursor is placed, it fluctuates in thickness, even though the CSS is static and absolute. Compare this next image to the one above, it is more narrow, and all I did was move the mouse a few pixels over:

[narrow cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfFfe.png)

From my research this is a consequence of subpixel rendering, which is fine, except I wouldn't expect a div with absolutely positioned and sized styles to fluctuate just because it is positioned in a different part of the screen.  I could understand if on some displays it was thicker, but then I'd still expect it to be consistent.

Does anyone have insight into this?  It's electron based so only chromium needs to be considered, and I'd rather not set the subpixel rendering off for the whole application just to address this one minor issue.

Comment: My guess is that you have your display scaled (e.g. in the "Display settings" in Windows 10)? This means your browser has to re-calculate every size and position of every element to scale it's appearance by 125% (or whatever the scaled amount is), and this can result in fractional pixels - which obviously don't exist so the browser has to compensate and this can lead to inconsistencies.

Comment: @FluffyKitten That's insane how spot on you are, disabling that fixes the issue completely.  Given that this is on an OS level, I assume there are no ways around it, but it's good to know that vast majority of users who have not adjusted scaling will not see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple options to detect and adjust the cursor based on the device scaling. Could look at [window.devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) to check the current size.

> The Window property devicePixelRatio returns the ratio of the resolution in physical pixels to the resolution in CSS pixels for the current display device. This value could also be interpreted as the ratio of pixel sizes: the size of one CSS pixel to the size of one physical pixel. In simpler terms, this tells the browser how many of the screen's actual pixels should be used to draw a single CSS pixel.

Or you could look into using [CSS resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution) for this.

```
// 76dpi * 1.25 = 95dpi; 96dpi * 1.25 = 120dpi; those are 2 common monitor resolutions
@media (resolution: 120dpi) { 
  .cursor {
    width: 2px; // just an example
  }
}
```